# PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_and_delete_option()

Tags: php, wordpress, flickr

I am working for a client who is using the [flickerRSS RU](http://gianlucacrema.com/blog/flickrrssRU/) plugin for WordPress. However when they try to put more than one calling of the function per page they get this error in the error_log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare get_and_delete_option() (previously declared 
in .../wp-content/plugins/flickrrss-ru/flickrrssRU.php:21) in 
.../wp-content/plugins/flickrrss-ru/flickrrssRU.php on line 21
```

First of the plugin calls is:

```
get_flickrRSSRU(array(
    'set' => '72157624558519886',
    'num_items' => 3,
    'type' => 'set',
    'html' => ' <a href="%flickr_page%" title="%title%"><img src="%image_square%" alt="%title%"/ height="68px" ></a>'));
```

Followed by:

```
get_flickrRSSRU(array(
    'set' => '72157624558519886',
    'num_items' => 11,
    'type' => 'set',
    'html' => ' <a href="%flickr_page%" title="%title%"><img src="%image_square%" alt="%title%"/ height="75" ></a>'));
```

I am not sure why these two calls would try to initialize the plugin again if it was loaded via WordPress.

I found out that this specific function being used is in the plugin as such:

```
$flickrRSSRU = new flickrRSSRU();
add_action( 'admin_menu', array(&$flickrRSSRU, 'setupSettingsPage') );
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array(&$flickrRSSRU, 'setupWidget') );
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( &$flickrRSSRU, 'setupActivation' ));

function get_flickrRSSRU($settings = array()) {
    global $flickrRSSRU;
    $flickrRSSRU->printGallery($settings);
}
```

Comment: does that function do an include/require? Might have to change it to a include_once/require_once to prevent that external function from being loaded/defined twice.

Comment: Yes it uses `if (!class_exists('flickrRSSRU')) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is it's line 49 in flickrrssRU.php

```
if (!get_option('flickrRSSRU_settings')) $this->setupActivation();
```

This one is likely calling `$this->setupActivation()` both times, which is declaring the `get_and_delete_option()` function inside of that method. It *should* have been creating the options when the plugin was activated, however it seems to be having trouble accessing it.

Look in your `wp_options` table and see if you can find the "flickrRSSRU_settings" key in there.

Alternative solution is to change line 21 of that same file from

```
function get_and_delete_option($setting) { $v = get_option($setting); delete_option($setting); return $v; }
```

to

```
if(!function_exists('get_and_delete_option')) {
    function get_and_delete_option($setting) { $v = get_option($setting); delete_option($setting); return $v; }
}
```

However if it's not finding the settings, you may run into other problems later.

Comment: It ended up being a missing setting in the database like you said, but I also added that fall back just incase it fails to load again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Various things could lead to the function being defined twice (or attempting to be). You can use [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) to check and see if the function already has been declared, and only declare it if it hasn't.

```
if ( ! function_exists('get_and_delete_option') ) {
    function get_and_delete_option( $foo, $bar ){
        return $foo . $bar;
    }
}
```

Come to think of it, I think this is the standard approach in WordPress to begin with.

#### Including, or Requring *Once*

If you're including this functionality, try using [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) or [`require_once`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) instead. This way, the same file won't be added in multiple times.